# Prove that a function is non-differentiable in (0,0)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the multivariable function
$f(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{x^{2}y}$. The problem is to find out whether it is differentiable in $(0,0)$ or not.
I have solved some similar problems before, the idea of the solution is to find a such path (for example $f(x, x^{2}))$ that the limit of the function, following the path, won't be equal to the function value in the point. The question here is: which path should I pick here? Can I take something like $f(x, \dfrac{1}{x^2})?$ In other words, which paths can be taken in order to solve those types of problems and why? Also, if the one I picked earlier doesn't work, which one I should go for?

Comment: A necessary condition for a function $f$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ is that the directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction of the unit vector $u=\left<u_1,u_2\right>$ is a linear function of $u$. In this case $$\left(D_{u}(f)\right)(0,0)=\lim_{t\mapsto 0} \frac{f(tu_1,tu_2)}{t}=(u_1^2u_2)^{1/3}$$ which is clearly non$-$linear, so $f$ isn't differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 4):

In first place, the idea you mention is about the relationship between "the paths" and "to show that a limit does not exist in several variables" and of course it is a good idea. However, you should *always* go in order in mathematical reasoning in particular for this kind of questions (in this case about the differentiability to function) it is about going to the definition of a certain object in mathematics and see *if each one of the conditions required by that definition are hold*. If the answer  is "yes, all conditions are holds" then you can conclude that the mathematical object meets the characteristics of that definition. Now, we will recall the  definition of differentiability for the case of mappings $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$.

> **(Differentiability** [one version]). Let $f: \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined over open set $\Omega$. We say that $f$ is differentiable function at interior point $(a,b)\in \Omega$ if and only if:
> $(1)$ The partial derivatives for $f$ there exists at $(a,b)$. 
> $(2)$ If $f$ satisfies, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(a,b)-f_{x}(a,b)(x-a)-f_{y}(a,b)(y-b)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}}=0.$$

So, define the function
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^{2}&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\ (x,y)&\longmapsto (x^{2}y)^{1/3}
\end{align*}
and we want to know if $f$ is differentiable function at $(0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ so we see in the definition:

$(1)$ In this part we can use the definition of "derivatives partial" . I will write the equalities directly, however you must first check if the limit exists the reason is formality, which is always important.

- $\displaystyle f_{x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(h^{2}\cdot 0)^{1/3}-(0^{2}\cdot 0)^{1/3}}{h}=0.$
- $\displaystyle f_{y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,h+0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(0^{2}\cdot h)^{1/3}-(0^{2}\cdot 0)^{1/3}}{h}=0.$

$(2)$ In this part just check,
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_{x}(0,0)(x-0)-f_{y}(0,0)(y-0)}{\sqrt{(x-0)^{2}+(y-0)^{2}}}&=\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}-(0^{2}\cdot 0)^{1/3}-0(x-0)-0(y-0)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}},\\ &=\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}
\end{align*}
Now, I suppose that you were asking about this part because the question here is: $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ there exists? and if the limit there exists is equals to $0$? Developing now your idea more precisely: you use the paths in the safe sense you know to show the reader that the limits you are working with does not exist. The natural question here is, is this the case? Let's see, the first impression is the denominator $x^2+y^2$, so we can think about a change of variable to polar coordinates before we start looking for paths and see if the limits coincide or not.

Setting the change of variables $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ with $\theta\in [0,2\pi[$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$, so
\begin{align*}
\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}&=\frac{((r\cos \theta)^{2}(r\sin \theta))^{1/3}}{\sqrt{(r\cos \theta)^{2}+(r\sin \theta)^{2}}},\\
&=\frac{r^{3/3}\cos^{2/3}\theta \sin^{1/3}}{r},\\
&=\cos^{2/3}\theta \sin^{1/3}\theta
\end{align*}
Now, the term $\cos^{2/3}\theta \sin^{1/3}\theta$ is of course bounded however *we cannot say* that the $\lim_{r\to 0} \cos^{2/3}\theta \sin^{1/3}\theta$ there exists and equals to zero because it depends the value of $\theta$. For example with $\theta=\pi$ we get $0$ but with $\theta=\pi/6$ we get $\sqrt[3]{3}/2$. Hence $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ there is not exists and since the condition $(2)$ fails therefore $f$ is not differentiable function at $(0,0)$ (but $f$ has a directional derivative in every direction at $(0,0)$).

Well, we already know that there is no limit.  However, can we do this by paths? By all means, look at the path $y=x^{2}$ and calculate the limit of a single variable and see if the limit exists or not i.e.,

- $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x^{2}x^2)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+(x^{2})^{2}}}=0$.

Now, see the path $x=y$ and notice that

- $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x^{2}x)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x^{2}}}$ and the limit there is not exits because $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{(x^{2}x)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x^{2}}}\not=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{(x^{2}x)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x^{2}}}$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^{2}y)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ there is not exists and hence $f$ is not differentiable function at $(0,0)$.

Now, also you are asking "which paths can be taken in order to solve those types of problems and why?" the answer for this question is "it depends about the domain of function $f$" for example for the mapping $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$ you cannot consider the path $x=-y$ because this line is not in domain of $f$. Now you see which path here you can or cannot take.

There are, of course, various ways of working with such problems as it. For example, first you should see if $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ (this is a weak way), a stronger way is to see if the partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous at $(0,0)$. It all depends on what theorems you know.